# Are there humans at all in NieR: Automata?

Tags: nier-automata

I'm watching NieR:Automata. At first I thought the resistance members were humans, but they are also androids like the ones from YoRHA but not exactly of the same type apparently. So I've searched some info in internet and found this is supposed to be a sequel of a videogame where Androids created by humans fight Machines created by aliens.

So, do humans still exist at all in this anime? What about the bosses who sent the androids to contact the resistance on Earth? What are they, humans or androids?

Are there humans at all in NieR: Automata?

Answer (score 3):

The bosses are androids, the same as 2B and 9S.

I haven't watched the anime, so I don't know whether the situation is any different there, but in the video game,

> it's revealed at the end of Route B that humanity has already gone extinct. So no, there are no humans in *NieR: Automata*, or at least, not in the video game.

Comment: What about Emil? The original is still alive according to Yoko Taro.

Comment: I think it's a bit of a stretch to consider what has become of Emil "human" anymore.